# angular sharing/sending validation data betvien views

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make 2tabs app using routeProvider ng-view and 2 controllers.At first tab would be user form. At second tab i want to show back to user what he entered with validation messages.

routing

```
project.config(["$routeProvider",function($routeProvider)
    {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {controller:'Ctrl1', templateUrl:'tab_1.html'}).
        when('/tab1', {controller:'Ctrl1', templateUrl:'tab_1.html'}).
        when('/tab2', {controller: 'Ctrl2', templateUrl:'tab_2.html'}).
```

To store data i use factory

```
project.factory('userService', function(){
    return{valids: {}}
})
```

and call it on my 2 cntrollers

```
project.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'userService', function(scope, rootScope, userService){
scope.data=userService;
```

And assign variables on controller html template

```
ng-model="data.input1"
```

After page(tab1) is loaded i have access to $dirty and $invalid values of my input.

```
scope.form.input.$invalid;
```

But when user switches to tab2 as i understand controller1 flushes, and i now ave only factory data and some vars that is send manually using $on('$routeChangeStart' function

The question is - what is the **best and correct** way to store/send/share these $dirty and invalid variables, to have access to them in second controller?
How to do it angular way?

Mb i need add them to factory data like so

```
scope.data.valids.input_invalid = scope.form.input.$invalid;
scope.data.valids2.input_invalid = scope.form.input2.$invalid;
```

Or add some controller(factory/directive?)?

Or manually write validation function(controller/factory/directive?) on controller2/2 scope?

Comment: Have you considered writing a service to store your user input/validation that both controllers can reference?

Comment: i use this to store data: project.factory('userService', function(){
    return{valids: {}}
}) Its service right? I bind inputs to this service variable... but what to do with scope.form.input2.$invalid and scope.form.input2.$dirty?

Comment: You should be taking care of your form validation on the view controller. Values should be "committed" to the service when it's satisfactory. You wouldn't want invalid data appearing in your second tab unless I'm confusing what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manny D is right. The best way to solve your problem is to create a service for storing input, and injecting it into each controller.  It looks like you could adapt userService for this purpose.

In the controller that is handling input, you can $watch the form, and call a setIsValid(scope.form.input.name, scope.form.input.$valid) method on the service to store the form's state when it changes.  Store the validity of each input on an object in your service.

In the other controller, you can add a reference to this service on the scope, and then data bind to the input-validity object's properties to surface them in your UI.